# Ball bounce in pong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written some code but can't get the ball to bounce on the floor or the ceiling naturally. Please help!

I've already tried getting the ball heading with ball_heading = ball.heading, but that didn't work

```
#Python 3.6.3
from turtle import *
import math
import random

#Screen Setup
bgcolor("black")
wn = Screen()
wn.title("Pong")

#Drawing Border
bd = Turtle()
bd.pencolor("white")
bd.pensize(3)
bd.hideturtle()
bd.penup()
bd.setposition(-400, -300)
bd.pendown()
bd.speed(0)
bd.pendown()
for line in range(2):
    bd.forward(800)
    bd.left(90)
    bd.forward(600)
    bd.left(90)
bd.penup()
bd.setposition(0, 300)
bd.setheading(270)
bd.pendown()
for dash in range(30):
    bd.forward(10)
    bd.penup()
    bd.forward(10)
    bd.pendown()

#Creating Paddles

#Paddle 1
player1 = Turtle()
player1.color("white")
player1.shape("square")
player1.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
player1.penup()
player1.setposition(-370, 0)

#Paddle 2
player2 = Turtle()
player2.color("white")
player2.shape("square")
player2.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
player2.penup()
player2.setposition(370, 0)

#Creating the ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.color("white")
ball.shape("square")
ball.speed(0)
ball.penup()
ball.setposition(0, 0)
ball.setheading(random.randint(0, 360))

#Moving the  player

playerspeed = 15
#p1
def move_up():
    y = player1.ycor()
    y += playerspeed
    #Setting the boundries
    if y > 245:
        y = 245
    player1.sety(y)

def move_down():
    y = player1.ycor()
    y -= playerspeed
    #Setting the boundries

    if y < -245:
        y = -245
    player1.sety(y)
#p2
def move_up2():
    y = player2.ycor()
    y += playerspeed
    #Setting the boundries
    if y > 245:
        y = 245
    player2.sety(y)

def move_down2():
    y = player2.ycor()
    y -= playerspeed
    #Setting the boundries
    if y < -245:
        y = -245
    player2.sety(y)

#Ball movement
def ball_fd():
    ball.forward(3)

#Ball ceiling / floor bounce
def ball_bounce():
    by = ball.ycor()
    if by > 279:
        by = 279
    ball.sety(by)

    bx = ball.ycor()
    if bx < -279:
        bx = -279
    ball.setx(bx)

#binding
listen()
onkey(move_up, "Up")
onkey(move_down, "Down")
onkey(move_up2, "w")
onkey(move_down2, "s")

#Making the ball move / main game loop
while True:
    ball_fd()
    ball_bounce()
```

Sorry the code is kind of long, but feel free to copy + paste it into IDLE or whatever.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You didn't turn the ball when it hit the floor or ceiling.

```
while True:
    ball.fd(3)
    by = ball.ycor()
    if abs(by) > 279:
        ball.setheading(-ball.heading())
```